# Deserializing JSON file with aeson in Haskell

Tags: json, haskell, deserialization, aeson

I'm new in Haskell. Currently I'm working on a SQL project and I got stuck on deserializing JSON file contents. I'm getting some cursed error and I don't know how to fix it.

This is my JSON file:

```json
{
"Table":"flags",
"Columns":[
  {"Name":"flag", "ColumnType":"StringType"},
  {"Name":"value", "ColumnType":"BoolType"}],
"Rows":[
  [{"Value":"StringValue a"}, {"Value":"BoolValue True"}],
  [{"Value":"StringValue b"}, {"Value":"BoolValue True"}],
  [{"Value":"StringValue b"}, {"Value":"NullValue"}],
  [{"Value":"StringValue b"}, {"Value":"BoolValue False"}]
  ]
}
```

This is my Haskell code:

```haskell
data FromJSONColumn = FromJSONColumn {
  deserializedName :: String,
  deserializedDataType :: String
  } deriving (Show, Eq, Generic)

instance FromJSON FromJSONColumn where

parseJSON (Object v) =
  FromJSONColumn <$> v .: "Name"
  <*> v .: "ColumnType"

parseJSON _ = mzero
```

This is the error I get:

```
JSONExample.hs:17:27-32: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘[Char]’ with ‘Key’
      Expected: Key
        Actual: String
    • In the second argument of ‘(.:)’, namely ‘"Name"’
      In the second argument of ‘(<$>)’, namely ‘v .: "Name"’
      In the first argument of ‘(<*>)’, namely
        ‘FromJSONColumn <$> v .: "Name"’
   |
17 |   FromJSONColumn <$> v .: "Name"
   |                           ^^^^^^

JSONExample.hs:18:12-23: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘[Char]’ with ‘Key’
      Expected: Key
        Actual: String
    • In the second argument of ‘(.:)’, namely ‘"ColumnType"’
      In the second argument of ‘(<*>)’, namely ‘v .: "ColumnType"’
      In the expression:
        FromJSONColumn <$> v .: "Name" <*> v .: "ColumnType"
   |
18 |   <*> v .: "ColumnType"
   |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Could somebody explain how to write instances for such files (files that contain tables) ? How should I do it? I'm truly lost.

P.S. This is the data types I'm working with:

```haskell
data ColumnType
  = IntegerType
  | StringType
  | BoolType
  deriving (Show, Eq)

data Column = Column String ColumnType
  deriving (Show, Eq)

data Value
  = IntegerValue Integer
  | StringValue String
  | BoolValue Bool
  | NullValue
  deriving (Show, Eq)

type Row = [Value]

data DataFrame = DataFrame [Column] [Row]
  deriving (Show, Eq)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second argument to the `.:` operator should be of type `Key`, but you're passing in a `[Char]` (also known as `String`).  Try one of the following to convert them into a `Key`:

1. Enable the `OverloadedStrings` extension.  I.e., add `{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}` to the top of the source code.
2. Instead of `"Name"`, try `fromString "Name"`. Likewise, instead of `"ColumnType"`, try `fromString "ColumnType"`.  `fromString` should be imported from the [Data.Aeson.Key](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-2.2.1.0/docs/Data-Aeson-Key.html) module.  This actually does the same thing as the first option, but the `OverloadedStrings` extension does this for you.